# Accessing Text File in a different Directory

Tags: java, file, directory, java.util.scanner

My File Structure

```
-Final_CS_Project (Root Folder)
    -UserCredentials.txt
-src
    -main
        -java
            -com
                -aking
                    -java
                       -Create.java
```

How can I access the text file? My current code does not work.

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("UserCredentials.txt"));
```

This error pops up:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: UserCredentials.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Tell us what other paths you have tried? A good trick is to *create* a new file in Create.java and see where it ends up. Then you know the default path and you can build a relative path from that to get to UserCredentials.txt.

Comment: I'll try that. I also copied the text file's relative path and tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: For some reason my Project was inside of another Project in IntelliJ and was saving the files to the other project.

Comment: I restarted the project and cleaned up the file structure. It works Thanks!